# Why does my Cucumber scenario fail with "Invalid keys :text, should be one of :text, ..."?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I have the following code to verify that a form only accepts date values in dd-mm-yyyy format.  However, I get the error

> Invalid keys :text, should be one of :text, :visible, :between, :count, :maximum, :minimum, :exact, :match, :wait

I presume this is caused by `fill_in arg2` in my step sefinition, but I can't figure out what is actually wrong.

Feature file:

```
Scenario Outline: Edit Person Validation
  Given I login
  And I edit a person
  When I enter <value> as <field>
  Then I should see <validity>

Scenarios: valid
| value         | field             | validity  |
| 20-05-2014    | person_startdate  | success   |
| JA-61-47-66-C | person_nino       | success   |

Scenarios: invalid
| value         | field             | validity  |
| 05-20-2014    | person_startdate  | failure   | 
| 2014-05-20    | person_startdate  | failure   | 
| 2014-20-05    | person_startdate  | failure   | 
| 20/05/2014    | person_startdate  | failure   | 
| 20-05/2014    | person_startdate  | failure   |
| 20/05-2014    | person_startdate  | failure   |
| 20/05-2014    | person_startdate  | failure   |
| 20'05'2014    | person_startdate  | failure   | 
| Today         | person_startdate  | failure   | 
| Tomorrow      | person_startdate  | failure   |  
| 2014          | person_startdate  | failure   |
| March         | person_startdate  | failure   | 
| 05-20         | person_startdate  | failure   |
| JH-22-43-61   | person_nino       | failure   |
```

Step definition:

```
Given /^I login$/ do 
  login "*****", "*****"
end

Given /^I edit a person$/ do
  visit edit_person_path('1682')
end

When /^I enter (.+) as (.+)$/ do |arg1,arg2|
  fill_in arg2, with: arg1
  click_on 'Save'
end

Then /^I should see failure$/ do
  expect(page).to have_text('div', text: 'prohibited')
end

Then /^I should see success$/ do
  expect(page).to have_selector('h1', text: 'Your People')
end

def login(username, password)
  visit login_path
  @user = User.create(username: username, password: password)
  fill_in "username_or_email", with: @user.username
  fill_in "login_password", with: @user.password
  click_on "Log In"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the error is in

```
Then /^I should see failure$/ do
  expect(page).to have_text('div', text: 'prohibited')
end
```

That's not how `have_text` is used. Do either

```
expect(page).to have_selector('div', text: 'prohibited')
```

or (only if you don't care about checking that the text is in a div, which maybe you don't since that's not a very specific selector)

```
expect(page).to have_text('prohibited')
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that error, but it fails before that step

Comment: I don't see how you'd get that error from `fill_in`. Better add your complete error to the question.